# Oracle 12c DBA_IDENTIFIERS is not populating when Oracle package is compiled from Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

```
Oracle 12cR1

Python 3.5

plscope_settings = IDENTIFIERS:ALL
```

**Requirement:** We have a requirement to identify start and end lines of sub programs inside a given Oracle Package.

**Design:** For this we are using `DBA_IDENTIFIERS`. The database parameter `PLSCOPE_SETTINGS` is already set to `IDENTIFIERS:ALL`. In order to populate the identifiers for a given Oracle package, we take the latest version of the Oracle package from our code version manager and compile it in development database. The compilation is done using `Python 3.5` scripts.

**Result obtained:** Post compilation, `DBA_OBJECTS` show this Oracle package with `STATUS` as `VALID`. So the package is compiled successfully. Yet  `DBA_IDENTIFIERS` is not getting populated for any given Oracle package. When the same Oracle package is manually compiled in `Oracle SQL Developer`, `DBA_IDENTIFIERS` is getting populated.

**Expected result:** When the Python script compiles the SQL files containing the Oracle Package and Package Body, `DBA_IDENTIFIERS` must get populated.

Are we missing something here? Any inputs will be greatly helpful.

-------------------Updated with modified version of Python code---------------

```
import cx_Oracle as ora
conn = ora.connect("myuser/mypwd@myservice")
cur = conn.cursor()
with open("/fodler1/folder2/pkh/mypkg.sql","r") as sqlFile:
    sql = sqlFile.read()
    cur.execute(sql)
with open("/fodler1/folder2/pkb/mypkg.sql","r") as sqlFile:
    sql = sqlFile.read()
    cur.execute(sql)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: It seems the problem lies in your Python scripts. So you'll probably need to post them here.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that Python/(library used to connect) does not override your plscope_settings?

Comment: @APC: I have updated a modified version of the python code that we used. @ Lukasz: I wasn't aware that the Python library could override plscope_settings database parameter. Let me check this.

Comment: Did you run `ALTER SESSION` or `ALTER SYSTEM`? , to change the settings.

Comment: @Kushik: No. plscope_settings = IDENTIFIERS:ALL is already set at database level.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Thanks. plscope_settings parameter was indeed getting overridden as you suggested. I added ALTER SESSION statement before the call to compile the package. It works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to check if library that you use to connect to Oracle DB does not override DB plscope_settings.

If yes, then you should add:

```
ALTER SESSION SET plscope_settings = 'IDENTIFIERS:ALL;
```